# Asp.net 3.0 and 64 bit sqlite dll file

Tags: asp.net

Greetings!

I am developing Asp.net application, in which i need to use sqlite as database, i tried to add reference to 64 bit dll file System.Data.SQlite file.
When i run my application it shows as below error
Error 1 Could not load file or assembly 'SQLite' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

What will be the reason for this, and how can i fix this.I am using visual studio 2010.

Thanks in advance
sangita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your application built to target 64 bit?  Or is it built to target AnyCpu and running on a 64 bit platform?

Have you tried using the 32 bit version of SQLite?  It sounds like you are trying to load the 64 bit version of the dll when you are in a 32 bit environment...

Comment: As your sugession , mostly i need to change the target platform